# AD (PAM) authentication stopped working after security update

Tags: samba, authentication, pam, active-directory

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 GIT server with AD authentication configured. Authentication stopped working yesterday while nothing on GIT server or AD has changed. Here's the error message:

> pam_winbind(sshd:auth): request wbcLogonUser failed:
>   WBC_ERR_AUTH_ERROR, PAM error: PAM_AUTH_ERR (7), NTSTATUS:
>   NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE, Error message was: Logon failure

I've noticed that there was an unattended security upgrade related to samba as you can see below.

> Start-Date: 2019-04-09  06:59:58 Commandline:
>   /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade Upgrade: python-samba:amd64
>   (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18, 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.19),
>   libwbclient0:amd64 (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18,
>   2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.19), libsystemd0:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21.16,
>   229-4ubuntu21.21), samba:amd64 (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18,
>   2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.19), samba-dsdb-modules:amd64
>   (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18, 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.19),
>   udev:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21.16, 229-4ubuntu21.21), libudev1:amd64
>   (229-4ubuntu21.16, 229-4ubuntu21.21), samba-libs:amd64
>   (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18, 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.19),
>   libpam-winbind:amd64 (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18,
>   2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.19), winbind:amd64
>   (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18, 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.19),
>   samba-common:amd64 (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18,
>   2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.19), systemd-sysv:amd64
>   (229-4ubuntu21.16, 229-4ubuntu21.21), libnss-winbind:amd64
>   (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18, 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.19),
>   libpam-systemd:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21.16, 229-4ubuntu21.21),
>   samba-vfs-modules:amd64 (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18,
>   2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.19), systemd:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21.16,
>   229-4ubuntu21.21), samba-common-bin:amd64
>   (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18, 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.19)
>   End-Date: 2019-04-09  07:00:51 (END)

I'm not very familiar with samba/pam authentication so I'm open to any suggestions on how to resolve it (other than rolling back).

https://usn.ubuntu.com/3939-1/ -> This seems to be the vulnerability that triggered the security update.

Answer (score 1):

In my case with slightly different error

> sshd[27281]: pam_winbind(sshd:auth): request wbcLogonUser failed: WBC_ERR_AUTH_ERROR, PAM error: PAM_AUTH_ERR (7), NTSTATUS: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE, Error message was: The attempted logon is invalid. This is either due to a bad username or authentication information.
> sshd[27281]: pam_winbind(sshd:auth): user 'myusername' denied access (incorrect password or invalid membership)

I had to turn off krb5_auth in /etc/security/pam_winbind.conf to make it work

> krb5_auth = no
> krb5_ccache_type =

Also, check that you have correct date and time on host, it should be in sync with time on domain controller.

Comment: Odd thing about this for me is our other Linux boxes have krb5_auth set to yes and can auth to AD just fine.  However, on a new VM, it didn't work and your answer fixed the problem (+1).  I'm not comfortable having them configured differently but at this point, I'm just glad that folks can log into it with their AD creds.  I validated identical krb5.conf, sshd_config, visudo, and pam_winbind before making this change so I'm unsure as to why it works on all others except this one.

Answer (score 0):

Caught a very similar problem, with RedHat 7, but perhaps my solutions applies to your case. My machine was joined to the AD Domain with winbind client configured, therefore allowing everyone from the domain to logon to it (joining with sssd client doesn't cause this behavior).

These "PAM_AUTH_ERR (7), NTSTATUS: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE" error messages began to appear on the log files when we tried to restrict SSH logins with the "AllowGroups" option on the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. There were an syntax error in the AD group that we configured, thus any logon attempt have failed, even members of this group.

After much head banging, we noticed the syntax error and then everything was fine (correct syntax is: AllowGroups "DOMAIN\group in lowercase", double quotes needed because the group name contains spaces).

Hope that it helps you!